# Comparing SQL datetime to C# DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I've been trying to find a proper solution for the following problem. I have an SQL table with a time column (in this format: `hh:mm:ss`). It contains a starting time for a program.

I now want to compare the time from said column to DateTime.Now and whenever the time in the column is identical to the time now a method should be called (for example).

I have several problems now:

1. I normally use `string startingtime = cmdx.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` to get a value from an SQL table but I'm not sure if it's clever to convert the time to a string here
2. My program is a windows service and will always run and I'm not sure if it's smart to use seconds when comparing the time from the SQL table to the time now because even a 1-second difference could mean the method won't be called.

My first try was this:

```
string startingtime = cmdx.ExecuteScalar().ToString();         
string timenow = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

var u1 = TimeSpan.Parse(timenow);
var u2 = TimeSpan.Parse(startingtime);
Console.WriteLine(u1 - u2);
```

I could then use the difference between `u1` and `u2` and let's say if it's smaller than one minute the program should start.
it's an OK solution but there might be a better way, I'm looking forward to your solutions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you fetch all rows, then decide in code, which to process? Why not query "where time < x1 and time > x2" in the first place? (x1 and x2 being the desired timerange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting the current date to a string and then using `TimeSpan.Parse()`, you should use the [`TimeOfDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday) property as it already returns a `TimeSpan`:

```
string startingtime = cmdx.ExecuteScalar().ToString();         

var u1 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var u2 = TimeSpan.Parse(startingtime);
Console.WriteLine(u1 - u2);
```

Then, comparing the difference in time against a certain threshold should be the way to go. You may use something like this:

```
TimeSpan diff = u1 - u2;
if (diff.TotalSeconds > 60)
{
    // Call your method here.
}
```

Moreover, depending on the type of your column in the database,  you might not need to call `.ToString()` and parse the result. If it's a date type, something like this could work:

```
var u2 = ((DateTime)cmdx.ExecuteScalar()).TimeOfDay;
```

Otherwise, if it's a string column, then `TimeSpan.Parse(startingtime)` would be fine.